# Error in binding json data from Ajax source in jquery data tables

Tags: c#, ajax, json, datatables

I am getting error in binding JSON data to constuct a data table.

My JSON is of the following:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Number": "2",
    "Name": "Avinash"
  },
  {
    "ID":2,
    "Number":"21",
    "Name":"XYZ"
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "Number": "20",
    "Name": "KRR"
  }
]
```

I am binding this to jquery datatable as below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#table_id').dataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": '<%:Url.Action("LoadData","Home")%>'
            });
            $('#table_id').css("width", "100%")
        });
```

My Table Structure is as follows:

```
<table id="table_id" border="0" class="display" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" align="center">
 <thead>           
            <tr>
                 <th>ID</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    </table>
```

I am getting error as follows:

```
  Datatables Warning(tableid="table_id"):Requested Unknown Parameter'0' from the datasource for row 0
```

My Controller is as follows:

```
public ActionResult LoadData()
        {
            var Data = new DataTable();
            Data=DataModel.LoadData();
            var JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, Formatting.None);
            return Json(new
            {
                aaData = JsonData
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Please help..

Comment: wheres ur <tbody></tbody>?

Comment: I added it..even then i am getting that error

Comment: had u try to pass as "aaData:[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Number": "2",
    "Name": "Avinash"
  },
  {
    "ID":2,
    "Number":"21",
    "Name":"XYZ"
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "Number": "20",
    "Name": "KRR"
  }
]"

Comment: My Controller is doing that..Please see my controller implemenatation

Comment: try define "aoColumns": [{ "sTitle": "ID" },
                    { "sTitle": "Number" }, { "sTitle": "Name" }] in datatable instead of at the table column and c whether it work